# C++ Compiler - Interaction between /Zi and /Od?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, compiler-optimization

In a release build on Visual Studio 2008 (though this probably applies to any Microsoft compiler), I can set /Zi ("Produces a program database (PDB) that contains type information and symbolic debugging information for use with the debugger. The symbolic debugging information includes the names and types of variables, as well as functions and line numbers.") and also /Ox ("Full Optimization").

These two flags are valid together, but seem to be in conflict.  One of the things the compiler might choose to do to fully optimize the code, is to rearrange code and change which code is in which line, but that screws up the information that the program database is compiling.

When I have both flags, which one "wins"?  Does my code get fully optimized, and some line numbers are not available?  Or does the optimizer get set to "less-than-full", so that it leaves line numbers alone?

Comment: There is no conflict between /Zi and /Od.  If you use /Ox then you get a "best effort" from the PDB.  It is serviceable, not ideal.  Using the /PDBSTRIPPED linker option is pretty common for the release build.

Comment: Thanks!  Why did you put this is a comment and not an answer?